# NSS Version Update For Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, certificates, browser, nss

Our root certificate added to NSS version which is 3.30.2 but on Ubuntu-16.04 the version of NSS is 3.28.4 thus our certificate appear as untrusted on browsers and we have receiving complaint. [This link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss) give information about which Ubuntu release have which NSS version. Ubuntu 17.10 have NSS version 3.32-1ubuntu3 but why not still NSS version updates get released for Ubuntu-16.04 so my question is when updates will get released for NSS(Ubuntu 16.04) or it will be or how can I get information about this subject?

Thanks for your answer.